# Nuxt middleware - is auth.js cached somewhere when running development server?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxtjs

I am new to nuxt and middleware and while I created a page and auth middleware which was working! I then deleted the test page and changed the redirect to an existing page as well as added a console.log message.

It seems that the middleware is cached somewhere because I am unable to see the changes that I made to the middleware js file and the redirect still tries to go to the deleted test page. I have tried in both SPA and Universal mode. I was able to create a new middleware that works which is why I think the original middleware is cached.

Am I correct that it is being cached and if so how can I clear it? (I have cleared my browser cache with no effect).

Comment: Looking at my vue dev tools I can see loggedIn:false, if I change to loggedIn:true then it redirects. Not sure why loggedIn:false after I receive a valid token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you are using `auth` (maybe even auth.js) as a middleware. You might have the `nuxt/auth` installed which claims that namespace for itself.

If so I would remove auth/nuxt and retry if the middleware works properly as stated in the nuxtjs documentation:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware